# Time travel novel with dragons and an old truck

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Looking for the title of a book likely published around 1980-1995 or so where the main character drives an old (1950s or 1960) pickup truck down a time travel "road" that others travel as well.  He is chased throughout the story by a dragon of some sort I think.  Cover showed the back of the old truck and maybe guns or a dragon tail.  Main characters were an old or older man I think, traveling with a younger man or boy. Not sure about that. The opening sequence has the older character stopped by some sort of time travel road policing agents as he is trying to take guns back to Sparta/Troy? to help them win a battle.

Comment: If you are back on the site, please click the check next to an answer so it is marked as solved. (They're essentially the same, but David's was first & he would benefit from the reputation.  I can't tell you which helped you the most, though.)

Comment: Yes, please mark one of the as "accepted". This will mark the question as solved and dish out some rewards! :)

Answer (score 23):

Probably *[Roadmarks](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/939645.Roadmarks?from_search=true)* by Roger Zelazny.

[image: Goodreads cover]

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roadmarks) summary:

> The narrator and protagonist, Red Dorakeen, has vague memories of a place or time that is no longer accessible from the Road. He runs guns to the Greeks at Marathon, trying to recreate history as he remembers it in an attempt to open a new exit from the Road to his half-remembered place.

Comment: That's a really strange cover image; it must be from a re-print edition.  (My copy has the cover pictured on Wikipedia.)  "A Night in the Lonesome October" was written 14 years later (1993 vs. 1979); I just checked.  (It looked so strange...)

Comment: @DavidW I grabbed the first one at Goodreads.  Matched my basic memory and I didn't really look at the blurbs or frame, honestly.  Looking into it, you're correct, it is from the 1994 reprint, but the picture is essentially the same as the 1979/80 original, just lighter and framed in blue.

Comment: This is a little disappointing, actually. I bought a con t-shirt once with that image, where the road sign had been (I now see) altered to the name of the city the con was in. I suppose I should have suspected that it was a bootlegged image, since there wasn't an obvious credit. Hopefully I can now redeem myself by tracking down the story, reading it, and telling people about it when they ask.

Answer (score 18):

[*Roadmarks*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1292) by Roger Zelazny.  The cover has the blue Dodge pickup truck and the dragon exactly as you describe.

[image: Original paperback cover of "Roadmarks" by Roger Zelazny]

As noted in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roadmarks) article, early in the novel the protagonist is trying to run guns to the Greek soldiers at the battle of Marathon; that matches very closely what you remember as well.  (He's trying to push history back into a configuration he remembers, which includes the Greeks winning at Marathon.)

The younger man may be Red's son Randy (C Twenty Cleveland) who goes looking for his father with the help of the AI called "Flowers of Evil."

Comment: That is it.  Wow, that was fast.  Thanks.